# Flipping coin simulation with gain/loss

Tags: r

Suppose you successively toss a fair coin and each time the result is
heads, you win $1, while if you get tails you lose 1$. Your initial capital is
3$. The throws stop if your capital is zeroed or you reach 10$. Let `X_n` be the
process that describes your chapter during the nth throw.
Simulate the `X_n` process 1000 times and present the graph
of its evolution through R.
2. Estimate the average number of consecutive throws until you stop. Is the result expected?

Can someone help me solve this or at least understand the steps I am supposed to take?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would help if you could tell us what you've tried so far. Is this homework, or self-study?  Homework questions are allowed on SO, but see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) for some advice on how to ask them effectively. `rbinom()`, `cumsum()`, `which()`, `replicate()` would all be components of an answer. (This scenario is also called the **gambler's ruin problem**, e.g. see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160819171419/https://statistical-research.com/simulating-the-gamblers-ruin/)) ...

Comment: ... or more generally do a search for "simulate gambler's ruin R" ... https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=simulate+gambler%27s+ruin+R

Answer (score 0):

Someone already posted a link to a solution of your homework in the comments. I fear, however, that this uncommented code is incomprehensive for you, given that you have asked the question in the first place.

I would therefore suggest to first write your own implementation with an outer `for` loop and an inner `while` loop conditioned upon the running capital, call `rbinom` in each run and recompute the running capital. Store the resulting runs in a numeric vector and call `mean` on this vector.

It will start becoming interesting when you measure the runtime of your solution, which will be surprisingly slow. To speed it up, you must use "vectorization", which the linked to solution uses, but this is a completely different topic to be left for a different lesson...